# Display a PNG image as is on an Android View (assistant allows only icons)

Tags: icons, png, imageview

I'm trying to create an Android View with a PNG image displayed as is in it. The only problem is, when I use the "ImageView" option, it will only allow me to create icons (Launcher icon, menu icon...etc.), which are too small to be displayed on my View!

I tried importing the PNG file in the drawable folders manually with "Link to file in the file system" option in the advanced options. That way, it does appear in the Graphical Layout of Eclipse as I want it to, but the XML file refers to a resource android:src="@drawable/myImage.png" that is "not found".

How to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

SOLVED **

Actually, what I did is enter the resource manually in the XML file of my activity as such:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
```

I put the file in all the drawable folders (xhdpi, hdpi, ldpi and mdpi) but in different sizes (200px width for ldpi, 300 for mdpi, 400 for hdpi and 480 for xhdpi). All files' name is myimage.png (but you should not put the extension in the code above!

PS: The reason for which it wasn't working before is that the file name's first letter was capital. I think...

Thanks anyway.

Sorry 'bout editing first post, but the site won't allow me to "answer my own question cuz I'm a newbie". :)